# weird iPhone 0x8badf00d crash report

Tags: iphone, multithreading, background, crash-reports, fmdb

I got a iPhone crash report when my app is brought to foreground, before that, the app is deleting some files, and i press HOME button to bring it background.

the weird thing is in the crash report, the Highlighted Thread is not 0, in my memory, the code 0x8badf00d exception's highlighted thread is always 0.

the thread 5 is doing some database operation, i used FMDB's queue mechanism to avoid multi-threads competition.

i wander know why the highlighted thread is 5 ? is the thread 5 block the main thread ?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

here is the crash report:

```objc
Date/Time: 2013-10-30 15:37:24.620 +0800 
OS Version: iOS 6.1.3 (10B329) 
Report Version: 104 

Exception Type: 00000020 
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d 
Highlighted Thread: 5 

Application Specific Information: 
com.xxxx.xxxx failed to resume in time 

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.010 (user 10.010, system 0.000), 100% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 7.631, 76% CPU 

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
Thread 0: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9bcc80 __unlink + 8 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ae8bc unlink + 4 
2 libremovefile.dylib 0x3b9027f8 __removefile_process_file + 236 
3 libremovefile.dylib 0x3b90288a __removefile_tree_walker + 114 
4 libremovefile.dylib 0x3b902a72 removefile + 118 
5 Foundation 0x340cec4e -[NSFilesystemItemRemoveOperation main] + 170 
6 Foundation 0x340cd5bc -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 836 
7 Foundation 0x340cc4fc -[NSFileManager removeItemAtPath:error:] + 80 
8 mCloud_iPhone 0x003037ae -[SDImageCache clearDisk] (SDImageCache.m:413) 
9 mCloud_iPhone 0x0032a1d2 -[AppSettingViewController clearCachesEvent:] (AppSettingViewController.m:365) 
10 UIKit 0x357330c0 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 68 
11 UIKit 0x35733072 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26 
12 UIKit 0x35733050 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40 
13 UIKit 0x35732906 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498 
14 UIKit 0x35732dfc -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484 
15 UIKit 0x3565141c _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 5764 
16 CoreFoundation 0x338156ca __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18 
17 CoreFoundation 0x338139bc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272 
18 CoreFoundation 0x33813d12 __CFRunLoopRun + 738 
19 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
20 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
21 GraphicsServices 0x373392e6 GSEventRunModal + 70 
22 UIKit 0x3569c2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116 
23 mCloud_iPhone 0x002d7c06 main (main.m:16) 
24 mCloud_iPhone 0x002d7bc8 ___lldb_unnamed_function8568$$mCloud_iPhone + 36 

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager 
Thread 1: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac648 kevent64 + 24 
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e54ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792 
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d7df4 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32 

Thread 2 name: WebThread 
Thread 2: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 WebCore 0x39774500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440 
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 3 name: com.crashlytics.MachExceptionServer 
Thread 3: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 mCloud_iPhone 0x00488940 ___lldb_unnamed_function16966$$mCloud_iPhone + 116 
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 4: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 mCloud_iPhone 0x003ec330 -[FXThreadManager threadFunc:] (FXThreadManager.m:263) 
7 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 5 name: Dispatch queue: fmdb.<FMDatabaseQueue: 0x1ede9bc0> 
Thread 5: 
0 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6e127c ___lldb_unnamed_function124$$libsqlite3.dylib + 35596 
1 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6d8482 sqlite3_step + 2138 
2 mCloud_iPhone 0x00429fca -[FMResultSet next] (FMResultSet.m:155) 
3 mCloud_iPhone 0x00454930 +[FXDatabaseOperator query:withVAList:withDatabase:resultType:] (FXDatabaseOperator.m:182) 
4 mCloud_iPhone 0x00454f54 __44+[FXDatabaseOperator queryWithDBFileID:sql:]_block_invoke (FXDatabaseOperator.m:236) 
5 mCloud_iPhone 0x00453124 __30-[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:]_block_invoke (FMDatabaseQueue.m:101) 
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d54b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e390a _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 22 
8 mCloud_iPhone 0x00453098 -[FMDatabaseQueue inDatabase:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:98) 
9 mCloud_iPhone 0x00454e16 +[FXDatabaseOperator queryWithDBFileID:sql:] (FXDatabaseOperator.m:235) 
10 mCloud_iPhone 0x000c5804 -[DatabaseManager queryPhotoBackupByFileName:] (DatabaseManager.m:1233) 
11 mCloud_iPhone 0x000dda50 -[CameraBackupManager queryBackUpDb:] (CameraBackupManager.m:2867) 
12 mCloud_iPhone 0x000d3bc4 __43-[CameraBackupManager synSystemlibraryToDb]_block_invoke_2 (CameraBackupManager.m:514) 
13 AssetsLibrary 0x330c7c5e __62-[ALAssetsGroup _enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:options:usingBlock:]_block_invoke_0125 + 102 
14 CoreFoundation 0x3383499e __NSArrayEnumerate + 394 
15 CoreFoundation 0x33796b66 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 58 
16 AssetsLibrary 0x330c78be -[ALAssetsGroup _enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:options:usingBlock:] + 718 
17 AssetsLibrary 0x330c7cd4 -[ALAssetsGroup enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:] + 24 
18 AssetsLibrary 0x330c9a0a __block_global_1 + 26 
19 CoreFoundation 0x3383499e __NSArrayEnumerate + 394 
20 CoreFoundation 0x33796b66 -[NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 58 
21 AssetsLibrary 0x330c9866 __block_global_0 + 1014 
22 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d611c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8 
23 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e4254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256 
24 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e43b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80 
25 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b90aa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358 
26 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b90a8a0 start_wqthread + 4 

Thread 6: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 mCloud_iPhone 0x003ec330 -[FXThreadManager threadFunc:] (FXThreadManager.m:263) 
7 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 7: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 mCloud_iPhone 0x00415acc +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4966) 
7 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 8 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader 
Thread 8: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 Foundation 0x340d33d0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304 
7 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 9 name: com.apple.CFSocket.private 
Thread 9: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9bc594 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20 
1 CoreFoundation 0x338191f2 __CFSocketManager + 674 
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 10: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 Foundation 0x340a9f92 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250 
7 Foundation 0x3414d860 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76 
8 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
10 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 11: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 mCloud_iPhone 0x003ec330 -[FXThreadManager threadFunc:] (FXThreadManager.m:263) 
7 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 12: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abf04 semaphore_wait_trap + 8 
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e482a _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 178 
2 TCC 0x38ef6682 TCCAccessPreflight + 218 
3 AddressBook 0x32fbc048 ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus + 4 
4 mCloud_iPhone 0x00132116 -[AddrBookObject accessToContacts] (AddrBookObject.m:141) 
5 mCloud_iPhone 0x00143fb8 -[ApnsManager isNotificationEnabled] (ApnsManager.m:96) 
6 mCloud_iPhone 0x0010798a -[AddressBookManager queryAutoSynSwitchStateForServer] (AddressBookManager.m:1046) 
7 mCloud_iPhone 0x00107876 __50-[AddressBookManager accessToTheServerSwitchState]_block_invoke (AddressBookManager.m:1008) 
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d611c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8 
9 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d5996 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$up + 142 
10 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d5890 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 32 
11 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e4212 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 190 
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e43b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80 
13 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b90aa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358 
14 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b90a8a0 start_wqthread + 4 

Thread 13: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9abeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ac048 mach_msg + 36 
2 CoreFoundation 0x33815040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 
3 CoreFoundation 0x33813d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 
4 CoreFoundation 0x33786eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 
5 CoreFoundation 0x33786d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 
6 mCloud_iPhone 0x003ec330 -[FXThreadManager threadFunc:] (FXThreadManager.m:263) 
7 Foundation 0x34156e80 __NSThread__main__ + 968 
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b91530e _pthread_start + 306 
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b9151d4 thread_start + 4 

Thread 14 name: Dispatch queue: fmdb.<FMDatabaseQueue: 0x1fbdf850> 
Thread 14: 
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x3b9ae898 pwrite + 20 
1 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b72e5c0 ___lldb_unnamed_function725$$libsqlite3.dylib + 44 
2 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6eedc8 ___lldb_unnamed_function200$$libsqlite3.dylib + 52 
3 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6ec332 ___lldb_unnamed_function190$$libsqlite3.dylib + 1106 
4 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6ebed2 ___lldb_unnamed_function189$$libsqlite3.dylib + 574 
5 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6ee126 ___lldb_unnamed_function195$$libsqlite3.dylib + 1150 
6 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6da2ba ___lldb_unnamed_function124$$libsqlite3.dylib + 6986 
7 libsqlite3.dylib 0x3b6d8482 sqlite3_step + 2138 
8 mCloud_iPhone 0x00426fee -[FMDatabase executeUpdate:error:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] (FMDatabase.m:902) 
9 mCloud_iPhone 0x00455e20 +[FXDatabaseOperator updateInTransaction:sql:] (FXDatabaseOperator.m:345) 
10 mCloud_iPhone 0x00250d44 __41-[NDDatabaseManager updateTransferTasks:]_block_invoke_0 (NDDatabaseManager.m:2353) 
11 mCloud_iPhone 0x00455bb8 __55+[FXDatabaseOperator doTransactionWithDBFileID:action:]_block_invoke (FXDatabaseOperator.m:307) 
12 mCloud_iPhone 0x004533b4 __46-[FMDatabaseQueue beginTransaction:withBlock:]_block_invoke (FMDatabaseQueue.m:125) 
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d54b4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e390a _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 22 
15 mCloud_iPhone 0x00453286 -[FMDatabaseQueue beginTransaction:withBlock:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:114) 
16 mCloud_iPhone 0x0045353e -[FMDatabaseQueue inTransaction:] (FMDatabaseQueue.m:143) 
17 mCloud_iPhone 0x00455a6e +[FXDatabaseOperator doTransactionWithDBFileID:action:] (FXDatabaseOperator.m:303) 
18 mCloud_iPhone 0x0025071c -[NDDatabaseManager updateTransferTasks:] (NDDatabaseManager.m:2386) 
19 mCloud_iPhone 0x002b14ae __50-[NDTransTaskDataManager startAllAutoPausedTasks:]_block_invoke_0 (NDTransTaskDataManager.m:1212) 
20 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8d611c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8 
21 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e4254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256 
22 libdispatch.dylib 0x3b8e43b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80 
23 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b90aa0e _pthread_wqthread + 358 
24 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3b90a8a0 start_wqthread + 4 

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

0x8badf00d: Reads as “ate bad food”! (If you squint your eyes and replace the digits with alphabetic characters. :p) This code indicates that an application was terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. Basically, the application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788

Comment: thanks! but my question is why the highlighted thread is 5? I saw a lot "bad food error", the highlighted thread is always 0